# Can I link a nether portal I made in the Overworld to a new one in the Nether?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I made my original nether portal next to my house, and it spawns me far away from the fortress. I found the fortress and made a new portal there, but the thing is, that portal teleports me to a location that is extremely far away from my house. Is there any way I can make that portal link up with my original portal in the Overworld next to my house? Or at least make it link up with a portal much closer to my house?

Answer (score 1):

For every block in the nether, you go 8 in the overworld, and portals follow this too. Say the fortress is 100 blocks away from your home nether portal (in the nether), and you make a portal there. When you go through it, you will be 800 blocks away from your house in the overworld. Portals link based on that math, so you can only choose where you want the portal in one dimension. You can figure out where a portal will go by dividing the x and z coordinates by 8 (overworld to nether) or multiplying by 8 (nether to overworld).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any other portals within 1000 block the portals will link.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do so. Once you put down the portal in the Nether, another portal simply shows up in the Overworld. It won't link to the one near your base.